# Let $f$ be a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ if $f'(x) \leq r \lt 1$ then prove or disprove that f has a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb R $.
>   If $f'(x) \leq  r \lt $ 1 then prove or disprove that $f$ has a unique fixed point.

I consider $f (x)=x+\frac {1}{e^x+1}$  to disprove the above statement. 
    Am I right?

Comment: It is a sloppy statement, I'd say. But ask yourself why $r$ is in the question. If $u<1$ then $u<r<1$ for some $r$. But in the above, correctly stated, $r$ is not meant to depend on $x$.

Comment: My guess is that you meant $\bigl|f'(x)\bigr|$ instead of $f'(x)$. Am I right?

Comment: If you meant $|f'(x)|\leq r<1$, then you can prove it, otherwise you can disprove it.

Comment: @Fakemistake No, you can prove it if $f'(x)\leq r<1$.

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x)=x-f(x)$ then $g'(x)=1-f'(x)\geq 1-r>0.$

So $g(x)$ is strictly increasing with a slope bounded below by a positive number.

Show that this means that $g(x)$ is neither bounded above or below, and thus $g(x)=y$ has a unique solution for any $y.$ In particular, for $y=0.$

Use the mean value theorem to show that $g$ is not bounded above or below.

If $N>0$ then you can conclude from the mean value theorem that:

$$g\left(x+\frac{N}{1-r}\right)\geq g(x)+N$$

and

$$g\left(x-\frac{N}{1-r}\right)\leq g(x)-N$$

---

Uniqueness follows from the mean value theorem, too.

If $x<y$ then $g(y)-g(x)=g'(c)(y-x)\neq 0.$

So $g(y)\neq g(x).$

Uniqueness just requires that $g'(c)\neq 0$ for all $c.$ Existence here needed that $\sup g'(c)<0.$

Comment: it's  only f'(x) not  |f'(x)|

Comment: so  my example is wrong because it is not possible to find a fixed bound r  which is strictly less than 1 .Am I right ? @lucas correa Sir

Comment: Yes, the $r$ in the problem should be a *fixed* $r$ for which the inequality is true for all $x.$

Comment: No not you sir @ Thomas Andrews ..but I can't get your hint. .will you please elaborate?

Comment: Which of my hint are you having a problem with?

Comment: @suchandaadhikari, yes! Thomas is absolutely right!

Comment: @Thomas Andrews how could one know $g$ must take the value $0$?

Answer (score 1):

> **Definition.** A function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is said a *contraction* when there is a $k \in [0,1)$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq k|x-y|$ for any $x,y \in X$.
>
> **Proposition.** *If $X\subset \mathbb{R}$ is closed, then any contraction $f: X \to X$ has a unique fixed point.*

**Proof (Hint).** Use the d'Alembert test for series and the continuity of $f$. For prove that the fixed point is unique, take two $a,b$ and use the contraction expression for show that $a = b$.

Now, prove that:

> **Claim.** Let $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function in interval $I$ with $|f'(x)| \leq k < 1$ for any $x \in I$ and $k \in [0,1)$. Then $f$ is a contraction.

**Proof (Hint).** Use the Mean Value Theorem.

A detail: the condition $|f'(x)| \leq k < 1$ is not equal to $|f'(x)| < 1$. This condition says there is a $k \in [0,1)$ **fixed** that bound $|f'|$.

Comment: You don't need $|f'(x)|$ - the statement above is true just as stated. It is true if $|f'(x)|<r<1$, that you can use that $f'$ is a contraction, but the case where sometimes $f'(x)\leq -r$ still has a fixed point.

Comment: (That last comment should have been: ... you can use that $f$ is a contraction ...)

Comment: how to show that  g (x) is not bounded above or bounded below Sir @Thomas Andrews

Comment: Thanks very much Sir. .I did not know about contraction @lucas correa

Comment: Sir I am trying to prove first ,the claim  using mean value theorem but here the condition is f'(x) $\leq $ r $\lt $1  not  |f'(x)| $\leq $ r $\lt $ 1...so I  can't show that f is a contraction .@lucas correa

Comment: If r is positive  then using mean value theorem it can be shown that f is a contraction but if r  is negative then I can't apply mean value theorem

Comment: @suchandaadhikari, yes. I assumed you were talking about the module, but as your case is more general, you don't need of this clam. The point is that I wanted to show you a good criterion to quickly identify whether or not there is a fixed point. For your specific case, use Thomas answer.

Comment: Alright. ...thanks very much Sir